# Huawei 3G modem disconnects after successful connection

Tags: 12.04, modem, 3g, huawei

I'm having a severe connection problem in Ubuntu 12.04 that renders the OS almost useless. I have a Huawei E352 3G modem. Ubuntu detects it as a mobile broadband connection without any problem. I created a new connection by providing APN. Now after connection it disconnects after a few seconds, and the modem disappears from mobile broadband list. I tried various workarounds but neither worked. I had no problem in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: What does dmesg say when it disconnects ? Does it show any error/info about the disconnection of the modem? I'm having the same kind of problem with my huawei E1732. Have you tried connecting the modem with the supplied 2-sided cable? Well believe me, it worked for me.. Also, give a shot to the Sakis3g script. http://www.sakis3g.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... See if you can enable Mobile broadband.

If not, open up the terminal and type in the following:

```
gksu gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

Find the entry:

```
# Huawei E352
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1449", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Disable it by adding an extra # in the beginning, before `ATTRS`:

```
# Huawei E352
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1449", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Save the file and reboot.. Should work..

I did for my Huawei E1550 3G device...

Answer (score 0):

## Install Huawei Mobile Partner 21!

This will install a specific driver for your 3G modem, which will save you from auto disconnection. 
Unofficial installation guide:
http://namakutux.blogspot.com/2012/07/bam-huawei-mobile-partner-for-linux.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem. Also when I tried connecting next day,it connected sometimes. But after getting disconnected once, I could not get it right again without waiting and trying several times or restarting my system and all.
This worked for me. See if this works for you too:

In windows, there is an User interface using which we can "Redial" until it gets connected finally. In Linux as there is no such User Interface, so we have to try ourselves. Whenever we insert the datacard, we can see the option of "Enable Mobile Broadband" in the Network Manager(title bar). First check it, then click on your Internet provider's name. If it does not get connected, try it again from the beginning. Remember to uncheck the "Enable Mobile Broadband" option first, then Re-enable it and then follow the steps again.

Reference: http://systemgenes.blogspot.in/p/off-topic.html

Comment: This theoretically answers the question, but it's better to include the relevant information from the link in your post.

Comment: @chaskes: EDITED now.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with your sim card, especially if connected to a router. The heat kills them. I was told this by  my service provider's help desk after trying what has been suggested in the answer. I told him he was talking nonsense (not so politely). Eventual I had the card tested, it was faulty. I have worked with hundred of cards in the past and never before had hassles. I now have a new sim card and no more problems.